# Changing nested object value in AngularJS changes all other values

Tags: javascript, angularjs

Consider the following nested object that loops 10 times to product a object with schedules for 10 weeks, for every monday at the given times:

```
$rootScope.bookings_times_list = [];
for (i = 0; i < 10; i++) {    
    $rootScope.bookings_times_list.push({
        week: i,
        schedule: [{
            booking_day: "Monday",
            booking_times: [{
                "booking_start_time": "00:15",
                "booking_end_time": "01:00",
                "booking_selected": "",
                "booking_selected_date": "",
                "booking_time": "30 Nov 2019 07:35hrs"
            }]
        }]                         
    });
}
```

The problem is that changing the `booking_selected` value to `1` as shown below changes the values for all `booking_selected` keys for every week to `1`:

`$rootScope.bookings_times_list[0].schedule[0].booking_times[0].booking_selected = 1;`

Why would this happen when the key for `$rootScope.bookings_times_list[0]` is clearly set to `0` for just the first week?

====UPDATE====

The actual code starts off with empty booking times like this:

```
$rootScope.bookings_times_list = [];
for (i = 0; i < 10; i++) {    
    $rootScope.bookings_times_list.push({
        week: i,
        schedule: [{
            booking_day: "Monday",
            booking_times: []
        }]                         
    });
}
```

Followed by another `for` loop that splices Monday and adds the actual time schedule available from the booking:

```
for (a = 0; a < $rootScope.bookings_times_list.length; a++) {
    for (y = 0; y < $rootScope.bookings_times_list[a].schedule.length; y++) {
        if($rootScope.business_bookings[$rootScope.bookings_index].booking_times[y]){
            var index = $rootScope.bookings_times_list[a].schedule.findIndex(x => x.booking_day === $rootScope.business_bookings[$rootScope.bookings_index].booking_times[y].booking_day);

            if(index >= 0){
                $rootScope.bookings_times_list[a].schedule.splice(index, 1, $rootScope.business_bookings[$rootScope.bookings_index].booking_times[y]);
            }
         }
    }
}
```

It appears the second `for` loop is the cause of the issue. Is the splicing affecting how the object is initialised?

===UPDATE===

I've also just noticed that it's not the splice that's the issue. Because changing from

```
$rootScope.bookings_times_list[a].schedule.splice(index, 1, $rootScope.business_directory_records[$rootScope.index].business_bookings[$rootScope.bookings_index].booking_times[y]);
```

to

```
$rootScope.bookings_times_list[a].schedule[index] = $rootScope.business_directory_records[$rootScope.index].business_bookings[$rootScope.bookings_index].booking_times[y]
```

in the second for loop still produces the same issue.

Comment: Works for me, see this fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/9jn3toL0/

Comment: You're actual code must be different than what is shown. Likely the actual code does an assignment of an object reference instead of using object literal notation.

Comment: @georgeawg, you're right. There's a second for loop that splices to add new values. I've update the question. Does the splicing affect the object?

Comment: @georgeawg, I've also just noticed that it's not the splice that's the issue. Because changing from `splice` to simply setting the value for the Monday schedule in the second for loop still produces the same issue. (As I've shown in the update)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `angular.copy`:

```
 .splice(index, 1, angular.copy(monday));
```

The `angular.copy` function creates new objects that do not share their contents.

For more information, see

- [AngularJS `angular.copy` Function API Reference](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/function/angular.copy)

Comment: `angular.copy` worked like a charm. Thanks, George!